# Create Cordova 2.2.0 Plugins

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've been wondering why my old plugins does not work in cordova 2.2.0. As I found out that there is a new structure in how to make javascript file for Plugins. I was able to make it work but I have a question.

Before I can do this.

```
window.plugins.pluginName.functionName(\"%@\");
```

Which would allow me to call `functionname` in from objective c to javascript.

How would that appply to the new format for 2.2.0 versions?

Answer (score 1):

The window.plugins object is no more. In your plugin's js code what you would need to do is:

```
if (!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
}
if (!window.plugins.pluginName) {
    window.plugins.pluginName = new pluginName();
}
```

and then it should act the way it used to without having to change the rest of your code.

Comment: Simon Would you pleaaase tell me how to fix the" public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray optionsArr, CallbackContext callBackId)" function in the LocalNotification Plugin for cordova 2.2 .... I can't find the solution anywhere & I really need it.